# Blender 2.8 - bevel modifier on a cube to which other objects have been joined

Tags: modifiers, bevel

Is it possible to bevel a cube that has been the subject of a join?

I am positioning text objects on the surface of the cube and then joining them to the cube; but this seems to interfere with the bevel modifier.  The surviving object is the cube.

I have created a cube and applied a bevel modifier successfully; but when I join something else to the cube, the bevel disappears.

I have also joined multiple items to the cube and then applied the bevel modifier (which doesn't work).

Thus, whether I apply the bevel modifier before or after the join, the result is the same - no apparent bevel!

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Try doing this: In the bevel settings, limit the bevel based on weight. Then, in edit mode, select only the edges of the cube, and set the bevel weight to 1.

Comment: Instead of Joining the meshes together you could Parent them, then they can retain their individual bevels and still be "attached"